# make transparent stickyHeader like weather iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

i  want to create transparent sticky header like weather app in iOS  as my header is transparent `view`  goes under header but i don't want other content visible bellow my header. ( you can see "Friday" goes under header and will hidden but the header is transparent).
you can check the animation and this behavior in weather  app.

[image]

i have tried :

[CSStickyHeader](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout)

Answer (score 2):

This is done with a combination of various scroll views and table views.

It looks like the whole screen is contained in a `UIScrollView`. The "header" is just a UILabel that moves depending on the content offset of the scroll view.

The time bar with "Now", "02", "03", ... Is probably a `UICollectionView` inside the main `UIScrollView`.

The section underneath that is a `UITableView` with all the day information. This is also embedded inside the `UIScrollView`.

The scrolling is then managed by the main `UIScrollView` and passed down to the `UITableView`.

However, when the tableview scrolls it is not going underneath anything. The content is being cut off because that is the top of the `UITableView`.

Then the entire thing is also embedded inside a `UIPageViewController` to manage the pages.

Something like this...

[image]

Comment: thank you  , but i don't  know , how can i implement this .  can you help me ?
the label on the top is not important for me , i need change position of the header box include   ( "now  , 02 , 03 ,) &  ... . can you make an example for me  or some thing like that ?

Comment: thanks for you image , but i need only create the behavior of table view & collection view  ( --> in scroll , collection view go from bottom to up , and staty in a position , and the table view item goes under it ) . 
another thing like page view controller & label not important for me ) 
very very thanks for you help

Comment: @MohamadFarhand You need to work the scrolling off the single UIScrollView delegate method. When the scrollview scrolls pass the content offset into the table view etc... so that it scrolls correctly where needed.

Comment: how can i  handle touch inside of scroll view & UiTableView ? 
i completely understand the `hierarchy` but a little need info to implement this

Comment: @MohamadFarhand not sure. You could do it several ways. You could disable scrolling on the UITableView maybe? Or pass the touches from the UITableView into the UIScrollView (or vice versa). Actually, I think the UITableView will pass the touches into the UIScrollView. (You could just disable interaction completely). The tableView in this case does not do anything other than display information so it doesn't need any touches.

Comment: is this true ? http://uupload.ir/files/qfgv_screen_shot_2015-10-08_at_12.19.05_pm.png
i want  my uitableview content hidden under My label  ( my label is like collection view )

Comment: @MohamadFarhand it looks like you've got the right idea. There are thousands of ways of doing this though. I imagine that Apple will have used separate view controllers for the table view etc...

Comment: @ can you help me how how can i add my `UITableView`  inside of UISCrollView ? and make my uiscrollView scrollable ?

Comment: @MohamadFarhand You could just set `UserInteractionEnabled` to false on the table view. That way the touches will be passed into the scroll view anyway.