# UICollectionView hide/prevent cell scrolling behind Sticky Header

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view with sticky headers

```
 flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
```

My issue is that the top half of my header is translucent and when I scroll my cell up I can see the cell scrolling behind the header.

I would like to hide the part of the cell view behind the header. In my image attached I do not want to see the green when it is behind the red. The rest of the behavior I want to keep as is.

The reason I need this is I have a wallpaper image at the very back which I need to be shown

[image: Sticky CollectionViewHeaders]

```
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
    collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: EXAMPLE_CELL_REUSE_ID, bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: EXAMPLE_CELL_REUSE_ID)
    collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: EXAMPLE_HEADER_REUSE_ID, bundle: nil), forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: EXAMPLE_HEADER_REUSE_ID)

    if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
      flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 100)
      flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
  }
}




func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return sections.count;
 }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1 //self.sections[section].1;
}



func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let exampleCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: EXAMPLE_CELL_REUSE_ID, for: indexPath) as! MyCellCollectionViewCell;

    exampleCell.headerLabel.text = "Cell"
    exampleCell.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

    return exampleCell;
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
    if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader {
      if let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: EXAMPLE_HEADER_REUSE_ID, for: indexPath) as? ExampleHeader {
       //  header.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)
        return header
      } else {
        return UICollectionReusableView()

      }
    }
    return UICollectionReusableView()
}
```

I think the question here may be similar but there are no responses and it is not quite clear if it is the same issue.
[Transparent sticky header ui collectionview don't show cells underneath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44739618/1463518)

Comment: Show the code that you have used.

Comment: The code is standard except for sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds. I posted it anyway

Comment: have you found the solution?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
    layout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
    layout.sectionInsetReference = .fromSafeArea
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView.anchor(top: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: 
    view.leadingAnchor, bottom: view.bottomAnchor, trailing: view.trailingAnchor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply mask for all cells that located under header view. Use on scrollViewDidScroll

Tutorial: https://medium.com/@peteliev/layer-masking-for-beginners-c18a0a10743

Answer (score -1):

I have created a very simple setup like yours and it is working fine.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource
{
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.collectionView.alwaysBounceVertical = true

        if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        {
            flowLayout.headerReferenceSize = CGSize(width: 400, height: 100)
            flowLayout.sectionHeadersPinToVisibleBounds = true
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int
    {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        return collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView
    {
        if kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader
        {
            return collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "rview", for: indexPath)
        }
        return UICollectionReusableView()
    }
}
```

Comment: What works fine? My collection view works, my question is how to have a transparent header, without seeing the cell behind it.

Comment: How did you make the header transparent? I mean the code to do that

Comment: Oh..really sorry..I didn't understand your question completely. This link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33010199/make-transparent-stickyheader-like-weather-ios might help you.

Comment: Thanks but not at all relevant

Comment: I don't think this kind of functionality is possible. I too searched for a solution  but couldn't find one.